# No results view freezes; doesn't change after adding new input

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am creating mobile GitHub repository search app and I've just figured out how to handle no responses with my friend, but this solution doesn't allow to change screens between the the `noResults` and `List` views (I commented them for you in var body).

The code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
private final class ContentViewState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoading = false
    @Published var query = ""
    @Published var stuff = [String]()
    @Published var noResults = false
   
    
    private var subscription: AnyCancellable?
    
    func fetchRepos(query: String) {
        isLoading = true
        subscription = Just("test")
            .delay(for: 2, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: {[weak self] (title: String) in
                self?.isLoading = false
                self?.stuff.append(title)
            })
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var state = ContentViewState()
    @State private var items = [Item]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if state.isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            } 

            //noResults view here
            else if state.noResults {
                HStack {
                    TextField("Enter search", text: $state.query)
                    Button("Search") {
                        state.fetchRepos(query: state.query)
                    }
                }
                Text("No results... Try again!")
            } 

            //List view here
            else {
                HStack {
                    TextField("Enter search", text: $state.query)
                    Button("Search") {
                        state.fetchRepos(query: state.query)
                    }
                }
                List(items, id: \.id) { item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(item.fullName).font(.headline)
                        Text(item.urlCode)
                    }
                }.task {
                    await loadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func loadData() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=" + state.query + "&per_page=20") else
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                state.noResults = true }
            return
        }
        
        do {
      
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data) {
                items = decodedResponse.items
                if items.isEmpty {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        state.noResults = true }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                state.noResults = true}
            
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, if you pass the valid input, i.e.: `Data`, `Core`, then you get the search results loaded into the app.

If you pass the invalid input, i.e.: `'Brigmhnst'`, you get `noResults` view, but if you pass the valid input from that state, you won't get the `List` view.

Both views look almost the same. The only difference is one of them is `else if` and the other is `else` and I can't have two 'elses', can I?

I have already tried adding the start-point view (similar to list View) bound to `else` condition, another list View with `else if` and created an `else` condition inside `do` in `func loadData` that would run if the items were not empty. The app seemed to work, but the first start-point view wouldn't swap to listView after passing the data in it (it is not in the code, since this solution worked worse than that I already have, but I can add it if you want to see it).

Comment: The else will work, It looks like you need to be authenticated to use this API, are you doing that?

Comment: Also, your fetch repos guy isn't actually modifying `noResults` or providing any items in the array you're using to populate the list.

Comment: You can use this API quite freely without an authentication, @Jake :) 

What do you mean by fetch repos modifying `noResults`? It's too big a level of abstraction for me. Could you please write some sample code?

Comment: Sorry I read those docs wrong lol

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the code you have.

First, I believe the models *(which are not included)* are incorrect. I pasted the JSON into quicktype.io and this is the result:

```swift
import Foundation

// MARK: - Repos
struct Repos: Codable {
    let totalCount: Int
    let incompleteResults: Bool
    let items: [Item]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case totalCount = "total_count"
        case incompleteResults = "incomplete_results"
        case items
    }
}

// MARK: - Item
struct Item: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let nodeID, name, fullName: String
    let itemPrivate: Bool
    let owner: Owner
    let htmlURL: String
    let itemDescription: String?
    let fork: Bool
    let url, forksURL: String
    let keysURL, collaboratorsURL: String
    let teamsURL, hooksURL: String
    let issueEventsURL: String
    let eventsURL: String
    let assigneesURL, branchesURL: String
    let tagsURL: String
    let blobsURL, gitTagsURL, gitRefsURL, treesURL: String
    let statusesURL: String
    let languagesURL, stargazersURL, contributorsURL, subscribersURL: String
    let subscriptionURL: String
    let commitsURL, gitCommitsURL, commentsURL, issueCommentURL: String
    let contentsURL, compareURL: String
    let mergesURL: String
    let archiveURL: String
    let downloadsURL: String
    let issuesURL, pullsURL, milestonesURL, notificationsURL: String
    let labelsURL, releasesURL: String
    let deploymentsURL: String
    let createdAt, updatedAt, pushedAt: String // Quicktype said these were dates, that didn't work
    let gitURL, sshURL: String
    let cloneURL: String
    let svnURL: String
    let homepage: String?
    let size, stargazersCount, watchersCount: Int
    let language: JSONNull?
    let hasIssues, hasProjects, hasDownloads, hasWiki: Bool
    let hasPages: Bool
    let forksCount: Int
    let mirrorURL: JSONNull?
    let archived, disabled: Bool
    let openIssuesCount: Int
    let license: JSONNull?
    let allowForking, isTemplate: Bool
    let topics: [String]
    let visibility: String
    let forks, openIssues, watchers: Int
    let defaultBranch: String
    let score: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case nodeID = "node_id"
        case name
        case fullName = "full_name"
        case itemPrivate = "private"
        case owner
        case htmlURL = "html_url"
        case itemDescription = "description"
        case fork, url
        case forksURL = "forks_url"
        case keysURL = "keys_url"
        case collaboratorsURL = "collaborators_url"
        case teamsURL = "teams_url"
        case hooksURL = "hooks_url"
        case issueEventsURL = "issue_events_url"
        case eventsURL = "events_url"
        case assigneesURL = "assignees_url"
        case branchesURL = "branches_url"
        case tagsURL = "tags_url"
        case blobsURL = "blobs_url"
        case gitTagsURL = "git_tags_url"
        case gitRefsURL = "git_refs_url"
        case treesURL = "trees_url"
        case statusesURL = "statuses_url"
        case languagesURL = "languages_url"
        case stargazersURL = "stargazers_url"
        case contributorsURL = "contributors_url"
        case subscribersURL = "subscribers_url"
        case subscriptionURL = "subscription_url"
        case commitsURL = "commits_url"
        case gitCommitsURL = "git_commits_url"
        case commentsURL = "comments_url"
        case issueCommentURL = "issue_comment_url"
        case contentsURL = "contents_url"
        case compareURL = "compare_url"
        case mergesURL = "merges_url"
        case archiveURL = "archive_url"
        case downloadsURL = "downloads_url"
        case issuesURL = "issues_url"
        case pullsURL = "pulls_url"
        case milestonesURL = "milestones_url"
        case notificationsURL = "notifications_url"
        case labelsURL = "labels_url"
        case releasesURL = "releases_url"
        case deploymentsURL = "deployments_url"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
        case pushedAt = "pushed_at"
        case gitURL = "git_url"
        case sshURL = "ssh_url"
        case cloneURL = "clone_url"
        case svnURL = "svn_url"
        case homepage, size
        case stargazersCount = "stargazers_count"
        case watchersCount = "watchers_count"
        case language
        case hasIssues = "has_issues"
        case hasProjects = "has_projects"
        case hasDownloads = "has_downloads"
        case hasWiki = "has_wiki"
        case hasPages = "has_pages"
        case forksCount = "forks_count"
        case mirrorURL = "mirror_url"
        case archived, disabled
        case openIssuesCount = "open_issues_count"
        case license
        case allowForking = "allow_forking"
        case isTemplate = "is_template"
        case topics, visibility, forks
        case openIssues = "open_issues"
        case watchers
        case defaultBranch = "default_branch"
        case score
    }
}

// MARK: - Owner
struct Owner: Codable {
    let login: String
    let id: Int
    let nodeID: String
    let avatarURL: String
    let gravatarID: String
    let url, htmlURL, followersURL: String
    let followingURL, gistsURL, starredURL: String
    let subscriptionsURL, organizationsURL, reposURL: String
    let eventsURL: String
    let receivedEventsURL: String
    let type: String
    let siteAdmin: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case login, id
        case nodeID = "node_id"
        case avatarURL = "avatar_url"
        case gravatarID = "gravatar_id"
        case url
        case htmlURL = "html_url"
        case followersURL = "followers_url"
        case followingURL = "following_url"
        case gistsURL = "gists_url"
        case starredURL = "starred_url"
        case subscriptionsURL = "subscriptions_url"
        case organizationsURL = "organizations_url"
        case reposURL = "repos_url"
        case eventsURL = "events_url"
        case receivedEventsURL = "received_events_url"
        case type
        case siteAdmin = "site_admin"
    }
}

// MARK: - Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}
```

Next, your `fetchRepos` function isn't doing anything. It's really only presenting a loader and stopping that later. The loadData function is actually what you want to use.

Finally, if you keep the task of `loadData` near the end of the code, you'll be in an infinite loop.

So these changes will clean it up a bit.

```swift
@MainActor private final class ContentViewState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoading = false
    @Published var query = ""
    @Published var items = [Item]()
    
    func loadData(query: String = "") async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=" + query + "&per_page=20") else {
            return
        }
        
        isLoading = true
        defer { isLoading = false }
        
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Repos.self, from: data)
            items = decodedResponse.items
            
        } catch {
            print("error \(error)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var state = ContentViewState()
    
    var searchView: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Enter search", text: $state.query)
            Button("Search") {
                Task {
                    await state.loadData(query: state.query)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if state.isLoading {
            ProgressView()
        } else {
            VStack {
                searchView
                
                if state.items.isEmpty {
                    Text("No results...\nTry again!")
                } else {
                    List(state.items) { item in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(item.fullName).font(.headline)
                            Text(item.htmlURL)
                        }.padding(.vertical)
                    }
                }
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}
```

The last thing you'll need to do is conform `Item` to `Identifiable`

```swift
extension Item: Identifiable {} // You could also just add Identifiable to the actual declaration
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, @Jake. Unfortunately some of this code is hard for me to understand yet. I will study it later.
Strange thing is, however I would copy the code, the starting screen is the error one :/

Comment: It could be that I have a typo in the model I didn’t correct here. Reops should be Repos

Comment: I did miss a couple of things when I copy pasted yesterday. I edited the answer, you should see those changes soon.